# Internet connection becomes extremely unstable after a few days

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, modem

I hope someone can help me with this annoying thing I started to experience after my ISP upgraded the lines in the neighborhood and gave everyone a newer modem/router combo. So my issue is that my internet connection becomes extremely unstable after a few days (usually 2-3 days) of usage randomly. Cannot open web pages, or they are extremely slow to open and also my own Asus router looses the WAN connection from the modem/router because the LED lamp on the Asus goes and comes back again randomly.

Here is my setup at home:

ISP modem/router(in bridge mode) ----> Asus ac86u router ----> network switch Netgear with 8 ethernet ports that I use.

One single ethernet cable goes from modem/router to Asus router, Asus router have 4 ethernet ports and they are in use by other devices, then one ethernet cable goes to the 
Netgear switch from Asus router and almost all the ports on the switch are used by other devices as well.

Here are the things I did to troubleshoot:

First few times it happened, I did this:

When I lose my internet connection, I restart the ISP modem/router then it works again. Or another time if I just restart my own Asus router, the connection works again.

Then I wanted to try other stuff when the problem occurs, so another time I did this:

I disconnected the Asus router and connected my desktop PC directly to the modem = internet worked again without problems with full bandwidth as it should be.
Then I again connected the Asus router to the modem/router and my PC to the Asus router = internet worked again without problems with full bandwidth as it should be.

So I didn't need to restart neither my Asus router nor my modem/router combo this time.

At first glance it would have seem that it's a router problem however I have tried several routers at home that I had lying around, and with all of them it's the same issue. There is a conflict going on somewhere that is my best guess, but what can cause such a thing? And another thing, is it normal that I have two IP addresses? Because my Asus router shows one IP, and my modem/router shows another IP? Can there be a conflict in such a thing?

Lastly I want to say that before my ISP upgraded the lines and giving us this new modem I had none of this issues at home on the same cables and previous modem/router from the ISP with my own routers.

So like I said when my internet works it works flawlessly with full bandwidth for 2-3 days until the problem occurs, then it's all suddenly bad.. I have 500mbit down and 200mbit up btw.

I'm really baffled and cannot find the root of the issue...

Comment: Connect a computer directly to the modem, bypassing your home network. Call the ISP Support and ask them to investigate

Comment: Did you contact your ISP about this issue?